# Did Select not work on table view?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, io

if i have table view with custom cell. Then i want to go different view from did select of table view.. then how can i do the same my code is here.

```
 [CCTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CCCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
     [CCTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    arraySuper=[NSMutableArray new];

     NSUserDefaults *userSave = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

       NSArray *KeysArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome - %@",[userSave valueForKey:@"userID"]], nil];
      NSArray *objectArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
        [self bindValues:KeysArray withObjects:objectArray];


       NSArray *KeysArray1=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Case Status",@"Open Delivery Cases",@"Open Claim Cases",@"Feedback Awaiting",@"Completed Good",@"Completed bad", nil];
     NSArray *objectArray1=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"",openDelieveryCase,openClaimCase,@"0",completeGood,@"0", nil];
  [self bindValues:KeysArray1 withObjects:objectArray1];

    NSArray *KeysArray2=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Today's Reminder",@"Case #123456 - Update Request by the insurer. Send Insurance Proof.1",@"Case #123456 - Update Request by the insurer. Send Insurance Proof.2",@"Case #123456 - Update Request by the insurer. Send Insurance Proof.3",@"Case #123456 - Update Request by the insurer. Send Insurance Proof.4", nil];
    NSArray *objectArray2=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"",@"",@"",@"", nil];
[self bindValues:KeysArray2 withObjects:objectArray2];
}

-(void)bindValues:(NSArray*) KeysArray withObjects:(NSArray*)objectArray
 {
 NSMutableArray *arrayMain=[NSMutableArray new];

 for (int i=0;i<[KeysArray count];i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[objectArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[KeysArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [arrayMain addObject:dict];
}

[arraySuper addObject:arrayMain];
}
```

//

```
 #pragma mark - Button Menu
 #pragma mark-

 -(void)buttonMenu:(UIButton *)button
{
 [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:nil];
}
```

//      

```
 -(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
    return arraySuper.count;
   }

   -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
 return [[arraySuper objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

  -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";
//CCCustomCell *cell
 cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[CCCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   }

     cell.keyText.text=[[[[arraySuper objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];
     cell.objectText.text=[[[[arraySuper objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

        [cell.objectText addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.objectText
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:nil
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:(cell.objectText.text.length>0)?50:0]];

if (indexPath.row==0)
{
    cell.keyText.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    cell.keyText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
}
else
{
    cell.keyText.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    cell.keyText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
    cell.objectText.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    cell.objectText.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];

}

 return cell;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
         cell.keyText.text=[[[[arraySuper objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];
cell.objectText.text=[[[[arraySuper objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

[cell.objectText addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.objectText
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:nil
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:  (cell.objectText.text.length>0)?50:0]];
if (indexPath.row==1)
      {
         NSLog(@"Csase Status Data");
         DetailCaseStatus *caseStatus = [[DetailCaseStatus alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailCaseStatus" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:caseStatus animated:YES];

  }

 }
```

Comment: did you know that "if (indexPath.row==1)" execute code only if you press the SECOND row of each section? Just for your information.

Comment: Yes i know.. But here did select is not working coz the data is in arrays and have section and i dont 9 how to retrive particular section

Comment: So what if data is in arrays and have section? I don't understand how it relates to didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called

Comment: I want to perform an action on did select.. but cz of sections it doesnot work dat is my question... In simple words how to get first section of table view.. so that in dat section i do my work or task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u try indexPath.section == (section with which you want to comapre)